# CLOS: convert symbol to accessor

Tags: common-lisp, symbols, accessor, clos

This is a real beginner question I guess, but I couldn't find the answer here. 
My problem: I would like to set the value of a slot of a class like so:

```
(setf (accessor class) value)
```

I wrote a small function for this:

```
(defun set-class-slots (class slot value)
      (setf (slot class) value))
```

I'm using this in a for loop, in which I'm iterating through 2 lists (slots (a list of symbols) and values (a list of numbers)) and would like to set several slots of an instance to the values.

```
(loop for slot in slots for value in values do
      (set-class-slots <myclass> slot value)
      )
```

The error I'm getting is:

"Undefined operator (setf slot) in form ((setf slot) #:|Store-Var-773597|#:g773598."

I think the problem is that the setf in my function does not use the value provided for the input arg. 'slot' but reads 'slot' as an operator.

I tried different things, symbol-function, funcall, etc. but don't know anymore what to do - as I also don't really understand what is going wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Marleynoe

Comment: Any reason you're not using `SLOT-VALUE`?

Comment: I'm working inside a lisp-based environment and for the classes I need to modify unfortunately SLOT-VALUE does not work (i.e. slot remains unmodified).

Comment: What environment is that?  Is it a Common Lisp implementation?  If not, please update the question's tags accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`FDEFINITION`](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/acc_fdefinition.html) to get the function value of a `(setf XXX)` function:

```
(defun set-class-slots (class slot value)
    (funcall (fdefinition `(setf ,slot)) value class))
```